# Image quality get low in Craft 3 after applying image transform

Tags: craft3, image-transforms, image, craft-pro

As of now I am using Craft's image transform to render images according to the size.  If this still appears low quality even Image Transform setting with qulity "Maximum".

Comment: Are you using the GD or Imagick image library on your server?  Imagick tends to produce higher quality output and supports a wider range of image formats.  You'll also want to make sure you're running recent versions of either.

Answer (score 1):

If the dimensions of the image are being displayed is larger than the transform dimensions it will show pixelation in the image. Just double up the dimensions of the transform image to see if this fixes it.